# Can this be written in 1 or 2 lines without tmp variable?

Tags: perl

I have this code

```
my $tmp = $q->param('owner');
$tmp =~ s/\s*//g; # remove white space from string
my @owners     = split ",", $tmp;
```

which works, but it takes up 3 lines, and it seams very wrong to use a temporary variable.

Can it be done in fewer lines and without a temporary variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
my @owners = map { s/\s*//g; $_ } split ",", $q->param('owner');
```

Since you're taking all the whitespace out, it doesn't matter whether you do it to the input or the list.

Of course, I use `map`-ped substitutions often enough that I've got a sub called `filter`, which looks like this `filter { s/\s*//g } ...` which is basically the same.

Comment: @ysth, wouldn't be the first time I re-invented the wheel. :) But I was in a CPAN-restricted shop as well. In addition, looking at the code, I like to make my list operators handle scalar contexts as well. So this works as well `my $trimmed = filter { /\s*//g } $val`

Comment: @ysth, yeah I see it now: `join( "", $scalar ) eq $scalar`

Answer (score 1):

```
my @owners = split /\s*,\s*/, $q->param('owner');
```

Comment: What about `one two, three four`?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I suspect the OP didn't actually want to remove *all* whitespace.

Comment: It's possible that he didn't intend it, but as written yours would give `['one two', 'three four']` where his original would give `['onetwo', 'threefour']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
my @owners = split(/\s*,\s*/, $q->param('owner');
```

**But you will still have the spaces that are not around the `,`**

Answer (score 0):

```
my @owners = $q->param( 'owner' ) =~ m{([^,\s]+)}g;
```